# deploying mezzanine 3.0 on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

does anyone have the proper guide to deploy mezzanine on heroku? I couldn't get gunicorn to work. 
My procfile is

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --noinput; python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

I saw there's fabfile.py which assist with gunicorn deployment. Could i utilize it for heroku? And how?

Comment: is it necessary to include collectstatic in procfile? Its been a while, but my last project had 'web: python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 1' in 'Procfile'. Also, Procfile is located in the same directory as manage.py, right?

Comment: Why are you not using wsgi as the offical [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#declare-process-types-with-procfile) state?